# Concatenate strings from char input

Tags: c, string, initialization, eof, c-strings

I want to Concatenate `strings` from char input.

I want to user will type char by char until `EOF` and then i want to pring my `string`.

So currently if i type `char` for exapmle 'r' hit `enter` and press `Control + D` (i am working on ubuntu) this is what i see on my screen:

```
r
r
�
```

This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char c = 0;
    char str[127] = {'\0'};
    while (c != EOF)
    {
         c = getchar();
         strncat(str, &c, 1);
    }

     printf("%s\n", str);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `EOF` is not a char. `getchar` returns int for a reason.

Comment: The code would be more user friendly if it detected newline `'\n'` as well as `EOF`. You should be building a `'\0'` terminated string to pass to `strncat`.

Answer (score 4):

Two issues here:

- `getchar()`  returns `int`. So `c` shall be an `int` as well, else it might not be able to store `EOF`.
- on the 1st iteration the code tries to concatenate to `str` which is uninitialised. Doing so invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: So what i need to change here ? (beside char c to int c)

Comment: @user979033: "*... to `str` which is uninitialised.*"

Comment: There are a few ways to initialise a string in C...Google will help :)

Comment: @user979033: Also take care when changing `c`  to be an `int` with what you pass to `strncat()`  as 2nd parameter then.

Comment: Might not be able to store `EOF`?   The reason `getchar()` returns an `int` is so it can report errors by returning values that a `char` cannot represent.  `EOF` is one such value.

Comment: @Peter -- if plain `char`s are `signed`, they are perfectly capable of holding the value of `EOF`. The value of `EOF` must be negative not to distinguish it from the range of `char` values, but to distinguish it from the range of values for the basic execution character set.

Comment: @DavidBowling And if `EOF==-200`? (Unlikely, but permitted.)

Comment: @aschepler -- well of course there are integer values which may not fit into a `char` (and which may be the value of `EOF`), and my comment could have been worded more carefully in this regard; but my comment was directed at the opinion that a `char` is _not_ able to hold the value of `EOF`. Alk was correct in the careful wording "might not be able to store `EOF`." The value of `EOF` may or may not fit in a `char`, and a `char` may or may not be able to take negative values, but no member of the basic execution character set can have a negative value.